# C# and EWS How to Save Message as an Email Instead of a Draft

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

What I have done so far is to connect to EWS, access my inbox, create an item (email) with some info in Body, Subject, From, and To, save it to the Draft folder, and finally move it to my inbox. It works, however, I get a draft in the inbox instead of an email.

Is it possible to get the message as an email with the above scenario and how can I achieve that?

Below is my code. Any input would be very appreciated.

```cs
try {
    message.Save();
}
catch(Exception e21) {;
}

message.Load(PS);

message.From = new EmailAddress("someone@abc.com");
message.ToRecipients.Add("me@abc.com");
message.Body = "This is A test take 1";
message.Subject = "Testing to send as someone else...";
// add in the attachments......
message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite); // require this here  why????
message.Copy(theTempFolder.Id); // get the item as a draft in my mailbox instead of an email 
}
catch(Exception e99) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception fail to connect to office 365 on the cloud: " + e99.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the MessageFlags property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessageflags-canonical-property to 1 (before you call update)  eg

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
message.SetExtendedProperty(PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read, 1);
```

Which will then make the message look like it was received. The other way is just import an EML like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-import-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send it to yourself with either message.Send() or message.SendAndSaveCopy() ? [see more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage?view=exchange-ews-api)